# p4 sync - subsequent call after interruption

Tags: perforce

What will happen if I cancel *`p4 sync`* during operation and then call again? Will it do all the work it has already done again?

And another one question: how and where does p4 store information about workspace file revisions? How does it know that I have n-th revision in workspace?

Does it store such a local workspace-specific information on the server's side or locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you interrupt a "p4 sync", it will pick up where it left off (at the file level of granularity -- if you're syncing a single large file it'll start over, but if you're syncing a lot of files it'll start with the next file after the last one that was synced successfully).

Information about which file revisions you have in your workspace is stored on the server.  Run the "p4 have" command to see this information for your workspace.  You can also run commands like "p4 files @otherclient" to see which revisions another workspace ("otherclient") has synced (e.g. if you're trying to reproduce a build from another workspace).